# Position of button in svg

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, position

Sorry.My confuse comes from my careless,I forget the css code has set a style for all buttons in the page,so every button will show at the upper-right corner,I consider that an unexpected position.:(

I want to put the wiggle button below the svg,while I just get it in the svg and overlay the update button,I can`t figure it out,help me,pleaz.Sorry for my web acknowledge in advance:(,code comes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Streamgraph</title>
<style>

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

</style>
<button onclick="transition()">Update</button>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var n = 20, // number of layers
    m = 200, // number of samples per layer
    zero_stack = d3.layout.stack().offset("zero"),
    wig_stack = d3.layout.stack().offset("wiggle"),
    exp_stack = d3.layout.stack().offset("expand"),
    sil_stack = d3.layout.stack().offset("silhouette"),
    layers0 = zero_stack(d3.range(n).map(function() { return bumpLayer(m); })),
    layers1 = zero_stack(d3.range(n).map(function() { return bumpLayer(m); }));

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, m - 1])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(layers0.concat(layers1), function(layer) { return d3.max(layer, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; }); })])
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .range(["#aad", "#556"]);

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .y0(function(d) { return y(d.y0); })
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("wmode","Transparent")
    .attr("height", height);
addElem(svg,"rect").attr({
            "width" : width,
            "pointer-events" : "all",
            "float" : "left",
            "height" : height
        })
        .style("visibility","hidden");

svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(layers0)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", area)
    .style("fill", function() { return color(Math.random()); });


d3.select("body")append("button").text("wiggle").attr("float","left").on("click",changewiggle);


function transition() {
  d3.selectAll("path")
      .data(function() {
        var d = layers1;
        layers1 = layers0;
        return layers0 = d;
      })
    .transition()
      .duration(2500)
      .attr("d", area);
}

// Inspired by Lee Byron's test data generator.
function bumpLayer(n) {

  function bump(a) {
    var x = 1 / (.1 + Math.random()),
        y = 2 * Math.random() - .5,
        z = 10 / (.1 + Math.random());
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      var w = (i / n - y) * z;
      a[i] += x * Math.exp(-w * w);
    }
  }

  var a = [], i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) a[i] = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) bump(a);
  return a.map(function(d, i) { return {x: i, y: Math.max(0, d)}; });
}

function changewiggle(){
    log("wig");
    layers0 = wig_stack(d3.range(n).map(function() { return bumpLayer(m); })),
    layers1 = wig_stack(d3.range(n).map(function() { return bumpLayer(m); }));

}

</script>
```

If u can,pleaz also tell me how to apply layout to wiggle without click the update button,the situation now is I click the wiggle button,then I must click the update button to see the chart update its graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely clear on all you want, but here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AjSv8/1/) after some adjustments. For one thing, I added the chart div to help position the wiggle button.

```
d3.select("#chart")
    .append("button")
    .text("wiggle")
    .attr("float", "left")
    .on("click", changewiggle);
```

But there were several other adjustments, like removing your addElem() piece which was causing errors, calling transition from the wiggle button code, etc. Anyways, let's see if this helps.

Comment: Sorry for my careless,I forget the css will fix all buttons in the page to right-upper corner,and sorry for my poor expression:(，but I think you just under my question.

Comment: @AlfredChen Sorry, I am not quite clear on your comment. Was this any help?

Comment: Your code answer my question correctly.I mean I stuck at my previous code is just because I`m careless and I waste your time:(

Comment: No waste of time...glad that it was helpful...thanks for acknowledging my effort.